# jinja2 variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2

If I have written jinja2 variables in javascript, for example

`var array = [{{count}}...`

and it works, will it work even if I move the code to a separate js file? Is there anything else I need to know about this practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly create a Jinja2 template that contains Javascript with Jinja2 variables, render that into a JavaScript file, and serve it to your users.  Jinja2 doesn't care what kind of file you are rendering.

An important consideration is that you are changing a static file to a dynamic file.  A typical Javascript file is static but you are now making it dynamic which puts additional load on your servers.

A typical solution is to use static JavaScript but render JavaScript data into your HTML page that the JavaScript file can access.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this looking for the same kind of solution, and it was pointed out to me somewhere else that the [data attribute in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is a good solution here as well.